# Animate on scroll not working on mobile as on desktop scroll.Top() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, web-frontend

It's my first time that i'm creating animations on scroll. I'm using documentsize variable and scrollTop() after reaching to the element i change the class of that element to do effect. It's working perfectly on desktop but on mobile only first element works and others not may be scrollTop() calculate differently on desktop and mobile so i need to use condition for applying different code for desktop and mobile. I'm not sure that's why i'm asking here if there is only this way.

Thanks.

```
 var documentsize = $(document),
  firstelement = $('.firstelement'),
  firstelementtime = 200,
  secondelement = $('.secondelement'),
  secondelementtime = 1400;


  documentsize.on('scroll',function(){

     if(documentsize.scrollTop() > firstelementtime){

         $('.firstelement').removeClass('myanimation');
         $('.firstelement').addClass('fadeInLeft');
     }


     if(documentsize.scrollTop() > secondelementtime){

         $('.secondelement').removeClass('myanimation');
         $('.secondelement').addClass('fadeInRight');
     }












     if(documentsize.scrollTop() < firstelementtime){

         $('.firstelement').removeClass('fadeInLeft');

           setTimeout(function(){

             $('.firstelement').addClass('myanimation');

           },500);
     }         



    if(documentsize.scrollTop() < secondelementtime){

         $('.secondelement').removeClass('fadeInRight');

           setTimeout(function(){

             $('.secondelement').addClass('myanimation');

           },500);
     }  

  });
```

Comment: Can you tag a working example?

Comment: No, Unfortunately it's not my personal data and i'm not authorized to share.

Comment: But, I said an example...

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about calculating different values in desktop and pc, its better to use either `$(element).offset()` to get top and left values according to the parent element or pure javascript `element.offsetTop.` After that you can use `$(parent).scroll()` to scroll down by the pixel value you get from the offset.

Comment: I think now i understand the problem. Actually on the desktop the height of elements is different than mobile so i need to change the numbers here for mobile in my code.
  firstelementtime = 200,
  secondelementtime = 1400;

Inways Edgars you answer is helpful.